# Attaching original message to SOAP fault

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a problem with fault handling with outFaultInterceptor. The task is to attach the original message to fault details like

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage msg) throws Fault {

    RequestData requestData = new RequestData();

    //SOAPMessage is anyType in RequestData WSDL type
    //HERE I SET THE ORIGINAL MESSAGE
    requestData.setSOAPMessage(msg.getExchange().getInMessage());
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ErrorContext ctx = new ErrorContext();
    //(...)
    ctx.setRequestData(requestData);

    ErrorInfoDetails errorDetails = new ErrorInfoDetails();
    errorDetails.setErrorMessage("Custom error message");
    errorDetails.setErrorCode("Custom error code");
    errorDetails.setErrorID("Custom error ID");
    errorDetails.setSeverity(ServerityType.CRITICAL);
    errorDetails.setErrorContext(ctx);

    ErrorInfo error = new ErrorInfo("Custom fault string", errorDetails);

    Fault fault = new Fault(error);

    msg.setContent(Exception.class, fault);
}
```

If I add it like above, in the reply message, the RequestData is empty.

If I add it with

```
    SAAJStreamWriter messageWriter = (SAAJStreamWriter) msg.getExchange()
            .getInMessage().get("org.apache.cxf.staxutils.W3CDOMStreamWriter");
    RequestData requestData = new RequestData();
    requestData.setSOAPMessage(messageWriter.toString());
```

It is being added as CDATA.
I'm pretty sure that there is some namespaces collision of those in newly created fault message and the original message's ones. Is there some neat way or some utilities to make them consistent?